# Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix, spdx

I created a new solidity contract. The contract is up and running but giving me this warning.

```
Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
```

There are no errors while compilation.

The Compiler version I am using in https://remix.ethereum.org/ is  **v0.7.5+commit.eb77ed08**
Language: Solidity
EVM VERSION: compiler default

Whenever I press compile it gives me the warning but there is no problem while deploying.

My code snippet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.5;
contract TestContract {
// Some logic
}
```

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.8/layout-of-source-files.html#spdx-license-identifier

Answer (score 123, accepted):

From Solidity ^0.6.8 SPDX license is introduced. So you need to use SPDX-License-Identifier in the code.

Have a look at this: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/solidity-0-6-8-introduces-spdx-license-identifiers/2859

For example in your code you need to use license identifier like

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.5;
contract TestContract {
// Some logic
}
```

You need to use license according to your project. Some other licenses are:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
```

You can find list of licenses here:
https://spdx.org/licenses/

Comment: Can you use a commercial (i.e. non open source) license?